# Sitefinity Dynamic Content Duplicate Key Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitefinity

Our company’s main site has been using Sitefinity for over a year now and we have one custom widget that uses a module created via module builder programmatically with a new custom widget in development. For both widgets we have recently started sporadically receiving the following error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint ‘pk_sf_dynamic_content’. Cannot
>   insert duplicate key in object ‘dbo.sf_dynamic_content’. The duplicate
>   key value is (581f9be9-f9b8-6ac8-bf63-ff000000686f). The statement has
>   been terminated.

We haven’t been able to find a pattern in when it happens. Is Sitefinity doing something to cause this? We've verified that it isn't being called twice. As a last resort, manually setting the id on the item didn't work.

Here's the snippet of code that causes the exception to be thrown:

```
DynamicModuleManager dynamicModuleManager = DynamicModuleManager.GetManager(String.Empty);

Type downloadType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Resources.Download");
DynamicContent item = dynamicModuleManager.CreateDataItem(downloadType);

var downloadID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
item.SetValue("DownloadID", downloadID);
item.SetValue("DateDownloaded", DateTime.Now);

item.SetString("UrlName", downloadID);
item.SetValue("Owner", SecurityManager.GetCurrentUserId());
item.SetValue("PublicationDate", DateTime.Now);
item.SetWorkflowStatus(dynamicModuleManager.Provider.ApplicationName, "Published");

// Attach User & Resource
var userType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Resources.User");
var userItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(userType).FirstOrDefault(d => d.GetValue<string>("UserID").ToString().Equals(user.UserID) && d.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Master);
if (userItem != null)
{
    item.CreateRelation(userItem, "User");
}

var resourceType = TypeResolutionService.ResolveType("Telerik.Sitefinity.DynamicTypes.Model.Resources.Resource");
var resourceItem = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(resourceType).FirstOrDefault(d => d.GetValue<string>("ResourceID").ToString().Equals(resource.ResourceId) && d.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Master);
if (resourceItem != null)
{
    item.CreateRelation(resourceItem, "Resource");
}

// Save Download
dynamicModuleManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;
dynamicModuleManager.SaveChanges(); //<== exception here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typically due to more than one item with the same urlname. This is a unique identified for sitefinty or the title field. Do a look up on this before you create the item to insure uniqueness.

Comment: Jon R is right - edit the Download module in the backend and see what its primary field is. If it is the Title field (which is by default) then make sure you set the Title field to a unique value (GUID) during the creation of the new item.